# LyX MiKTeX path

Tags: lyx, miktex

I am trying to install a package with MiKTeX to use with LyX editor on Ubuntu 18.04.

It seems MiKTeX put packages in one directory and LyX reads from another.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: how can I resolve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have you tried matching those paths? What have you tried so far? Have you read [this post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13381)?

Comment: Hi, I am really thankful for you trying to help. I read this post, but wasn't able to get help from it. I am very new to linux, miktex and lyx. I tried to change folder path from within Lyx, but i didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the paths known to Lyx. You can do so in Tools > Preferences > Path > PATH prefix
[image]

Then probably you have to click the Recongigure menu (Tools > Reconfigure) and then re-start Lyx.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it didn't work, I also see the files in the Tex information. Meanwhile I switched to Texmaker, works perfect

Comment: Hello. You might find more information about what is going wrong in the Messages pane. View menu > Messages pane, and then try to compile the document again.